# Is the complimentary student filing of a CV still happening?

Tags: support, status-deferred, jobs, students

Hello, sometime last year(note, it may have been in January or February) I noticed the student filing feature of Careers. I of course took the student filing option which was free. Now has it really already been a year since then? My CV is now listed as "unfiled". And if so, then why is there the option to take the student filing again? (I don't want to abuse the free privilege of Careers, so I'm asking here).

Also, is it possible to get some kind of email or other notification when our CV changes to unfiled?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and refile your CV checking the "I'm a student" check box. We're very trusting that way.

In terms of an expiration email, it's not something we're looking to implement immediately, but a nice feature down the line.